# driver.getWindowHandles() behaviour

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I was reading about driver.getWindowHandles(), somewhere I read 'it will return the window handles in the order how they were opened'.

However, when I use it in realtime, it's not the case.

```
    public void checkAllWebpages() {
    
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    
    for(int tab = 1; tab<=5; tab++) {
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tab));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, WebDriver loops through opened tabs however, it goes from last to first instead of first to last(Goes from right to left instead of left to right).

Let's say I have only one tab opened right now and let's call it 'a'. Now I open 5 tabs in order 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'.

If I run the above code now, WebDriver will loop through the tabs in the order 'f', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', instead of 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

*"I read somewhere.. why does it actually work in other way than I read somewhere"* - that's kind of bad question here.

The order in which window handles are returned is defined in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-window-handles) that states:

> The order in which the window handles are returned is arbitrary

which means there is no special order. It is up to a particular webdriver how to order the handles.

Comment: Okay. What you said makes sense. However, even though getWindowHandles returns a set, it actually returns a linkedHashSet which in turn maintains insertion order. So my question is why it always iterates from right to left instead of left to right? Is it always like that? If not, how do you make sure you are accessing the exact tab you need? I'm just starting with Selenium so too many questions in my head. Sorry!

Comment: The singular getWindowHandle method will return the driver's current window handle.  A new window/tab will have a handle that is not equal the current.  This is how you track them because each handle is unique.   (Iterate through the getWindowHandles array to see which is new...)  Different browser(s) drivers have return different orders here... or even different kinds of window handles based on local vs remote.  (I think Firefox for instance will have a different handle when the new tab/window is blank, than it does after loading a remote url...)